# run .exe as administrator on a vm with Invoke-VMScript Powershell 7

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, invoke-command, powershell-7

I need to be able to launch command by shell console or powershell having the administrator window in powershell 7.

I have launched several commands with Start-Process but none of them returned the desired value. I was getting back that I needed an interactive screen or just an error.

```
Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList "-noexit","-File", "file url" -verb runas -Wait
Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList "-noexit","-File", "file url" -cred credentials -Wait
```

I also used a function I found, but it doesn't return anything either, it gives me an error that it can't add the line '$startinfo.verb = "RunAs"'.

```
Function Elevate-Process  {

    param ([string]$arguments)

    $startinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

    $startinfo.FileName = "powershell.exe"

    $startinfo.Arguments = $arguments

    $startinfo.verb = "RunAs"

    $startinfo.UseShellExecute = $false

    $startinfo.CreateNoWindow = $true

    $process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($startinfo)

}
```

all of this launched through the Invoke-VMScript

Answer (score 0):

I have no excperience with VMScript but I recently had a similar effect.
My situation was:
(1) elevating a cmd file *myCmdFile.bat* from a powershell script with

```
Start-Process aCmdFile.bat -Verb RunAs
```

(2) the content of *myCmdFile.bat* is

```
pwsh.exe -File "C:\Mark\Temp\myScript.ps1" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -wait:$true .... (and all other parameters)
pause
```

(Here is no need for *-Verb RunAs* because it inherits the admin rights from the cmd file.)

This worked for me, but when I used *powershell.exe* instead of *pwsh.exe* nothing happened.
So try to use ***pwsh.exe***!
By the way also if the cmd file is on a network drive and you have not hacked the registry.